# Adding images to the gridview using drawable

Tags: java, android, gridview, layout

how to add images to gridview from drawable and 
I need the checkbox also for the image if i select the image it needs to store the position in arraylist

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. It worked for me

```
private ArrayList<Integer> Gallery_Images = new ArrayList<Integer>();

 Resources resources = getResources();
 Gallery_Images.add(R.drawable.gallery_img_one);
 Gallery_Images.add(R.drawable.gallery_img_two);
 Gallery_Images.add(R.drawable.gallery_img_three);
 Gallery_Images.add(R.drawable.gallery_img_four);
 Gallery_Images.add(R.drawable.gallery_img_five);
 Gallery_Images.add(R.drawable.gallery_img_six);
 gridView.setAdapter(new Image_Custom_Adapter(this, Gallery_Images));
```